# How can I customize the logic of test paralleling in junit5

Tags: java, junit5

I have this code:

```
private static Stream<int> testData(){
    return Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).stream();
}

@ParametrizedTest(name = "{0}")
@MethodSource("testData")
void checkTest(){
     //...
}
```

and i can run it in parallel, but how can i customize? 
For example - i want run test in two threads as
the first - checks even numbers
second - check odd numbers?

Comment: documentation for concurrent tests is [online](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution)

Comment: anything beyond has to be implemented by yourself via Java concurrency indeed